Real Analysis - Relationship between pointwise convergence of functions and the set they converge on
I'm reading Sheldon Axler's book on Measure Theory. Here is the start of the proof of a theorem.

$(3.7)$ Egorov's Theorem

Suppose $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ is a measure space with $\mu(X) < \infty$. Suppose $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ is a sequence of $\mathcal{S}$-measurable functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that converges pointwise on $X$ to a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Then for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a set $E \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $\mu(X \setminus E) < \epsilon$ and $f_1, f_2, \ldots$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $E$.

$\color{SkyBlue}{\textsf{Proof}} \quad$ Suppose $\epsilon > 0$. Temporarily fix $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. The definition of pointwise convergence implies that
$$
\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=m}^{\infty} \left\{ x \in X : |f_k(x) - f(x)| < \frac{1}{n} \right\} = X. \tag{2.86}
$$

I don't understand why formula $(2.86)$ is true. I know that it comes from the definition of pointwise convergent functions, but how can this be true? Why does taking the intersections and then unions make it equal to $X$?

This is a way of describing convergence: $$\forall n\exists m\forall (k\ge m),{ |f_k(x)-f(x)|<{1\over n}}$$

It is just a matter of grinding through.
Suppose $y \in X$ and $f_k(y) \to f(y)$. Then there is some $m$ such that if $k \ge m$, then $|f_k(y)-f(y)| < {1 \over n}$.
In other words, $y \in \{ x | |f_k(x)-f(x)| < {1 \over n} \}$ for all $k \ge m$, or equivalently, $y \in \cap_{k=m}^\infty \{ x | |f_k(x)-f(x)| < {1 \over n} \}$.
Since $f_k$ converges pointwise everywhere on $x$, we see that for each $y \in X$ there is some $m$ such that the last containment holds. This is equivalent to
$X \subset \cup_{m=1}^\infty \cap_{k=m}^\infty \{ x | |f_k(x)-f(x)| < {1 \over n} \}$.

Should the last equation be $X = ...$ ?

@HelloVictor2000 Well, yes, but the other direction is implied, I dropped the $x \in X$ on the right hand side for brevity.

Ok, I see. Thank you so much!
